# Different object dynamically in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I build a custom FlatList , because my View is the same and i dont want to duplicate code.

1. I exec the flat list like this:

   ```
      <FlatListPicker
                   data={availableMeetings}
                   type="days"
                   updateSelect={selectHandler}
                   selected={selectedDay}
               />


                   <FlatListPicker
                       data={availableMeetings[0].hours}
                       type="hours"
                       updateSelect={selectHandler}
                       selected={selectedHour}
                   />
   ```
2. The custom flat list look like this:

   ```
      const FlatListPicker = ({ data, type, updateSelect, selected }) => {
      return (
       <FlatList
       horizontal={true}
       data={data}
       renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <TouchableOpacity
               style={[
                   styles.button,
                   selected === item.key && styles.buttonselected,
               ]}
               onPress={() => updateSelect(item.key, type)}
           >
               <Text
                   style={[
                       styles.daytext,
                       selected === item.key && styles.textselected,
                   ]}
               >
                   {item.dayName}
                   {"\n"}
                   {type === "days" ? (
                       <Text style={styles.datetext}>{item.date}</Text>
                   ) : (
                       <Text style={styles.datetext}>{item}</Text>
                   )}
               </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
           />
         );
        };
   ```
3. Everything working good. but like you see i need to pass prop called "Type" to decide what to show in the component, (because otherwise objects Item is different and i cant access to the properties of the objects),  so its look little bit weird, for example:

   ```
       {type === "days" ? (
                       <Text style={styles.datetext}>{item.date}</Text>
                   ) : (
                       <Text style={styles.datetext}>{item}</Text>
                   )}
   ```
4. **My question**: there is a way to access dynamically to item properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use javascript logical operator

**try this**

```
<Text style={styles.datetext}>{item.date || item}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a duplicatio of your code my bro the best approach to do so with [tornary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy):

```
   const FlatListPicker = ({ data, type = "days", updateSelect, selected }) => {
   return (
    <FlatList
    horizontal={true}
    data={data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={[
                styles.button,
                selected === item.key && styles.buttonselected,
            ]}
            onPress={() => updateSelect(item.key, type)}
        >
            <Text
                style={[
                    styles.daytext,
                    selected === item.key && styles.textselected,
                ]}
            >
                {item.dayName}
                {"\n"}
               <Text style={styles.datetext}>{type === "days" ? item.date : item }</Text>
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
         )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      );
     };
```

Comment: Thanks.  Actually i used in the comment of mehran. Ita more shortly

Comment: @RoeiGrinshpan Good Luck